# Google cloud backing up while the server is down and need reactivate

Tags: backup, google-compute-engine, google

I have been using it since January and it says that I have 90 days and $300. I think it ended on 31 May 2021 but I when I contacted support service it ended on 4 April 2021. So I have exceeded the deadline and the trial credit. Fortunately I was not charged because I have no funds in my bank account. But sadly, I have not backed up my data from that server. I need help with how to backup my data after the project was suspended, and with how to reactivate it. I don't have the money to reactivate my project and run my server back.

Please help.

Comment: You have up to 30 days after your project was suspended to reactivate your project. If you have exceeded 30 days, Google can delete everything.

Answer (score 1):

As it was already mentioned by *@John Hanley* at the comment section, you have up to 30 days after your project was suspended to reactivate your project.

You can find more details at the documentation section [End of the Free Trial](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#end):

> **The Free Trial ends when you use all of your credit, or after 90 days, whichever happens first**. At that time, the following
> conditions apply:
>
> - To continue using Google Cloud, you must [upgrade to a paid Cloud Billing account](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#how-to-upgrade).
> - All resources you created during the trial are stopped.
> - **Any data you stored in Compute Engine is marked for deletion and might be lost**. [Learn more about data deletion on Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/security/deletion#deletion_timeline).
> - Your Cloud Billing account enters a 30-day grace period, during which you can recover resources and data you stored in any Google
>   Cloud services during the trial period.
> - You might receive a message stating that your Cloud Billing account has been canceled, which indicates that your account has been
>   suspended to prevent charges.

in addition to that at the documentation section [Upgrading to a paid Cloud Billing account](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#how-to-upgrade):

> - *If you upgrade within 30 days of the end of the trial*: Your resources are marked for deletion, but you might be able to recover
>   them. Learn more about data deletion on Google Cloud.
> - **If you upgrade more than 30 days after the end of the trial, your Free Trial resources are lost**.

As a result, if your services were suspended on 4th of April there's no data to restore.